# Is it safe to use write() multiple times on the same file without regard for concurrency as long as each write is to a different region of the file?

Tags: node.js

According to [the docs for fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback):

> Note that it is unsafe to use fs.write multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream is strongly recommended.

I am downloading a file in chunks (4 chunks downloading at a time concurrently). I know the full size of the file beforehand (I use `truncate` after `open`ing the file to allocate the space upfront) and also the size and ultimate location in the file (byte offset from beginning of file) of each chunk. Once a chunk is finished downloading, I call `fs.write` to put that chunk of data into the file at its proper place. Each call to `fs.write` includes the position where the data should be written. I am not using the internal pointer at all. No two chunks will overlap.

I assume that the docs indicate that calling `fs.write` multiple times without waiting for the callback is unsafe because you can't know where the internal pointer is. Since I'm not using that, is there any problem with my doing this?

Comment: So the official docs say its unsafe and you are asking random SO ppl if its safe.  Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

No its not safe. Simpy because you don't know if the first call to `write` has been successful when you execute the second call.

Imagine if the second call was successful but the first and third call wasn't and the fifth and sixth were successful as well.
And the chaos is perfect.

Plus NodeJS has a different execution stack than other interpreters have. You have no guarantee when specific code parts will be executed or in which order

Comment: Any chunk that fails to be written is handled fatally and the entire download is abandoned. And even then, it's checking the file's hash once everything's done and if something got corrupted somewhere along the way it will detect that. The reason I wonder is because the docs suggest using createWriteStream because that guarantees order, but I don't care about order.

Comment: You cant handle it when you dont wait for the callback 

Comment: I'm *handling* the callback, I'm just not *waiting* for it before I write again.

Comment: In C, `pwrite` to no override regions concurrency is safe. If we could wrapper it to nodejs interface it's useful.

Comment: Node already does. The remark about unsafeness does not apply when the position argument is given. `fs.write` calls `pwrite(2)` when given the `position` argument.

Comment: Thank you @DanD. That's exactly what I suspected might be the case.